# Links to stop jobs notifications 404

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Can't stop job notifications from the email as

- Unsubscribe from this email
- Edit job alerts
- Edit email settings

The links are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/unsubscribe-all?id=d1a22e5e0d644709afe5079605bedc89&auth=XXX
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?id=d1a22e5e0d644709afe5079605bedc89&auth=XXX
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/?id=d1a22e5e0d644709afe5079605bedc89&auth=XXX

￼
All return 404 [image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted support. Turns out I had somehow linked 2 email addresses / profile together and the notifications were enabled on my secondary email address / profile but coming to my main email address.